# Changing only orthographic size and only changing Pixel to units for low resolution sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, screen-resolution, orthographic

I'm wondering, if this is a good practice?

For now highest resolution I will support is `1920x1080` and I will change everything according to this.

Aspect ratios are not problem, I will create extra content.

For lower resolutions I will load sprites dynamically and set appropriate value for `Pixel to units`'s property to fit my highest resolution.

if for `1920x1080` sprites there are `100 Pixels to units`, for `480x270` there will be `25 Pixels to units`.

This will allow me to have constant units across all resolutions.

The reason I'm thinking this is not good, is because when I manually tried to set the `orthgraphicSize` to fit other resolutions I got some numbers like these:

```
Resolution         Orthographic Size
320x240      =>    7.2
800x480      =>    5.763
1280x800     =>    6.002
1920x1080    =>    5.4019
```

If this is alright, anyone have function to convert these `resolutions` to `orthographicSize` or suggest me some method to create this function?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just scaling your items.

Comment: Can you like to be more specific why this would fail?
Because i think when i will be scaling the items i will need to fight with translating units to world space...